# Как добавить AdMob в Android-проект?

Tags: java, android, admob, android-manifest, firebase-android

Я все делал по инструкции от Firebase(Tools -> Firebase -> AdMob), но после запуска на эмуляторе приложение вылетает и в консоли пишет эту ошибку:

```
2021-07-18 16:52:57.012 4998-4998/com.example.javagb_android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.javagb_android, PID: 4998
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    
    ******************************************************************************
    * The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
    * should follow the instructions here:                                       *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
    * to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
    * Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
    ******************************************************************************
    
    
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6396)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    
    ******************************************************************************
    * The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
    * should follow the instructions here:                                       *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
    * to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
    * Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
    ******************************************************************************
    
    
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbdz.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.2.0:20)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.2.0:1)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6391)
            ... 10 more
```

Я пробовал и другие способы, но видимо они не актуальны и сделаны под AS 2.2.2 Нужно ли мне переходить на 2.2.2 или и на 4.2.2 можно все сделать? Если да, то как? Заранее спасибо!

Вот код на джаве:

```
package com.example.javagb_android;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class First_main extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "First_main";

    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_main);

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

Вот xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/space_bg"
    tools:context=".First_main"
    tools:ignore="MissingClass">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="118dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            ads:srcCompat="@drawable/user_avatar" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Вы [не забыли](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#configure_your_app) указать App ID в файле AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: А где там этот ID ставить?

Comment: Добавил [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1306545)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Проверьте ваш AndroidManifest.xml, укажите App ID в теге `meta-data` внутри тега `application`, в соответствии с [документацией](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#configure_your_app):

```xml
<manifest>

    <application>

        ...

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```